# Problem with Update in CRUD during unit tests because of Bcrypt encryption

Tags: junit, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am hashing my user passwords while saving the entities to the database.
While doing that, I'm unable to update the username, without hashing the password again.

I wrote the test for it, which fails.

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Update")
public void testForUpdate() {
    final User user = new User("UserForUpdate", "UpdatedUser123");
    this.userService.save(user);
    User found = this.userService.findOneByUsernameAndPassword(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
    assertTrue(found.getId() != null, "Found real user");
    this.userService.save(found);
    final User asserted = this.userService.findOneByUsernameAndPassword(found.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
    assertTrue(asserted != null, "Updated user found");
    assertTrue(user.getId() == asserted.getId(), "User ID is persisted");
}
```

The save method from the UserService looks like this:

```
@Override
public User save(User newUser) {
    newUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newUser.getPassword()));
    return repository.save(newUser);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong saving it like this?

How should I proceed, to implement the CRUD Update correctly?

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify the password when you store the user. Instead encode the password when you modify it.

```
public class UserSevice {

    ...

    public changePassword(User user, String plainPassword) {
       user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(plainPassword));
    }

}
```